# Tachometer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a tachometer in Python, but when I Google for research about it, only programs for Raspberry Pi come up. The script I'm looking for is when I press start there will be a timer that counts down from 60s and wherever I say "stop" it will calculate how long it look to get me to 1km therefore knowing my velocity.

E.g. 1km in 30 seconds = 120km/h

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't count down in seconds:

```
for number in range(100,0,-1):
    print(number)
```

Comment: Add line `time.sleep(1)` as the next line after `print(number)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the time module for this and an input could work as a stop.

```
import time
input('press enter to start')
start = time.time()
input('press enter to stop')
end = time.time()
result = end - start
print('You are going at {0} km/h.'.format(60.0/(result/60)))
```

Comment: thanks so much! but the press enter to start doesn't work you have to input any key then press enter to start or stop it